# Convert two line breaks into one line break

Tags: php

Let's say for example somebody enters into a textarea:

```
line
line
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
line line
```

And if someone enters

```
line

line
```

It displays as

```
line
line
```

Stackoverflow does this too, but I want to know how to do it specifically with PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean in an input field in the browser? Probably a Java script would suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$search = ['~(?<!\s)\h*\R\h*+(?!\s)~', '~\h*(\R)\h*+\s+~'];
$replace = [' ', '$1'];

$str = preg_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

Where `\R` is a linebreak (whatever the OS). `\h` is an horizontal whitespace and is used here to trim leading and trailing spaces. *(to be more rigorous, you can replace all `\h` with `[^\S\r\n]`)*

Comment: Gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' `

Comment: @EthanWebster: It's because you use an old php version, replace `[...]` by `array(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "";//your input here;
$output = preg_replace('@\n+@', "\n", preg_replace('@(.+)\n{1}(.+)@', '$1 $2', $input));
echo nl2br($output); //result as html
```

it's simple, use regex 1st replace only matches where is one new line into space and then replaces matches where is more than one new line sign to just one new line

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my problem. If I have just one line break between two elements they do not appear side-by-side.

Comment: what input do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$text=$_POST['text'];

    $array = explode("\n",$text);
    $count = count($array);
    $j = 0;
    foreach($array as $value){
        $j++;
        if(!empty($value)){
            echo $value;
            if($j > 1){
                echo '<br />'; // OR "/n"
                $j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```